Why does flask stringify integer keys in a response JSON
Why does flask stringify the integer keys in this JSON response?
app.py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/test', methods=['GET'])
def test_endpoint():
    return {1: "test"}, 200

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

test_app.py
import pytest
from app import app

@pytest.fixture
def client():
    app.config['TESTING'] = True
    with app.test_client() as client:
        yield client

def test_test_endpoint(client):
    response = client.get('/test')
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.json == {1: "test"}

This will fail with the error
====================================================== FAILURES ======================================================
_________________________________________________ test_test_endpoint _________________________________________________

client = <FlaskClient <Flask 'app'>>

    def test_test_endpoint(client):
        response = client.get('/test')
        assert response.status_code == 200
>       assert response.json == {1: "test"}
E       AssertionError: assert {'1': 'test'} == {1: 'test'}
E         
E         Left contains 1 more item:
E         {'1': 'test'}
E         Right contains 1 more item:
E         {1: 'test'}
E         Use -v to get more diff


Because object keys are always strings (excluding array indices)

specific redirection to flask from title will help as context is not clear when coming from python - suggest close with duplicate

I realised specifically in python this is why json.dumps({1:2}) will yield {"1": 2}

The stack creating the JSON does not matter since you're creating JavaScript Object Notation

JSON keys must be strings. Did you read the spec? It fits on a notecard.... https://www.json.org/json-en.html
